# loop is not repeating and won't stop

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

[image]

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
function OnEvent(event, arg)
if IsKeyLockOn("numlock" )then


         if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
         
                Sleep(50)
                MoveMouseRelative(0, 1)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(0, 16)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(0, 26)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(-2, 25)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(10, 28)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(8, 25)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(10, 15)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(-14, 15)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(-34, -1)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(-18, 0)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(10, 10)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(-13, 5)
                Sleep(100)
                MoveMouseRelative(-20, -5)
                Sleep(100)
       
          end
  coroutine.resume(cor)
  repeat
     Sleep(100)
     coroutine.resume(cor)
  until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
        end
    end
```

Trying to move mouse to one direction and after sometime move to another and loop need to be stopped soon as i left go of the button.

Currently its running entire loops even after let go of the button and it won't repeat when i don't let go of the mouse. please check the gif.

Thanks

Comment: Why `coroutine.resume(cor)` is here?  BTW, coroutines are excluded from GHub implementtion.

Comment: Try to replace each `Sleep(100)` with `if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then return end; Sleep(100)`

Comment: removed the coroutine, replaced all the lines, added repeat on the top and everything working perfectly now, super thanks :)